# probability problem with the intersection of 2 events given

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

The question is:

1.) Of a group of patients having injuries, 28% visit both a physical therapist and a chiropractor and 8% visit neither. Say that the probability of visiting a physical therapist exceeds the probability of visiting a chiropractor by 16%. What is the probability of a randomly selected person from this group visiting a physical therapist?

What I gathered while trying to find the answer is:

$A\cap B\:=.28$

$A'\cap B'\:=.08$

$1.0 - (0.28 + 0.08) = .64$

The confusion comes from figuring out what $A$ and $B$ is with the remaining info:

> **physical therapist exceeds the probability of visiting a chiropractor by 16%.**

venn diagram open for editing [here](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1St6UabRp3cTfFH3XX7H7Zh27abVGKMQHStnwxDJYpvs/edit?usp=sharing).
[image]

*note:* the answer for the question is $0.68$

Comment: You should have written $ P (A' \cap B') = 0.08 $. $ P(A' \cup B') $ is unknown. The question states that 0.08 of the patients do not see a physiotherapist or a chiropractor, which means that they belong to both $ A' $ and $ B' $.

Comment: @MichaelR I've made the edit, I will take a look over again and see if I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ A $ denote a physiotherapist visit and $ B $ denote a chiropractor visit.

What is the probability of visiting a physiotherapist? $ P(A) $

What is the probability of visiting a chiropractor? $ P(B) $

We are told that the probability of visiting a physiotherapist exceeds the probability of visiting a chiropractor by 16%, which means that:

$$ 0.16 = P(A) - P(B) $$

Recall the formula for the intersection of two events: $ P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) $

Let $ 0.16 = P(A) - P(B) $ be equation 1 and let $ P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) $ be equation 2.

Then add them together to get:

$$ 0.16 + P(A \cap B) = P(A) - P(B) + P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) $$

You can now solve for $ P(A) $, i.e. $ P(A) = \frac{1}{2} \big(0.16 + P(A \cap B) + P(A \cup B) \big) $

Substituting $ P(A \cap B) = 0.28 $ and $ P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(A' \cap B') = 1 - 0.08 = 0.92 $ into this equation, we find that $ P(A) = 0.68 $.

Comment: how do you go about finding $P(A \cup B)$?

Comment: $ P (A \cup B) = 1 - P(A' \cap B') = 1 - 0.08 = 0.92 $.

Answer (score 0):

Since $P(A \cap B) + P(A' \cup B') = 1$, we have
$$
P(A \setminus B) + P(B \setminus A) = .64.
$$

Assuming that $A=chiropractor$ and $B=therapist$, the remaining info says that
$$
P(B) = P(A)+.16.
$$

Can you take it from there?